# how to move character move on a circular surface in only one direction?

Tags: unity, rotation

Making a 2d game:

I want to move character on circular surface only in one direction?

Script attached to child object is:

```
    public GameObject ball;
    float speed=2f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Left();
    }

    void Left()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
            //transform.Rotate(Vector2.left);
        }
    }
```

**Note:**
character will move on a circular surface in only one direction...

**Image reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need polar coordiates. you need to find the position in polar **coordintaes(radius,teta)** to unity basic **cartesian coordinates(x,y)**
you can move the object by changing the theta angle
this is my example code:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach (var item in PolarElements)
        {

            float x = item.radius * Mathf.Cos(item.myAngle);
            float y = item.radius * Mathf.Sin(item.myAngle);

            item.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x+  x,transform.position.y+y,transform.position.z);
            item.myAngle += item.speed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is PolarElements it is vector2 / Ienumarator?? what is PolarElements,Which value store in polar 90degree or 180 degree?? that is vector 2??